# CSS displaying is not right

Tags: html, css

Below is a preview (made in Photoshop) of how my list must look like:

[image]

Below is the CSS code that I have:

```
.newsFeed {
    float: left;
    width: 728px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.newsFeed li {
    width: 233px;
    height: 244px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 10px solid #dddddd;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}

.newsFeed li img.image {
    width: 226px;
    height: 157px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

If you calculate the margin resulted from 3 list elements `10px*3 = 30px` you will know that instead of 3 items per line, I only get two items. How can I remove the border of the last element in a line?

```
(instead of this)
+-----------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---+---+---|
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
+-----------|

(I get this)
+-----------+
| 1 | 2 |   |
|---+---+   |
| 3 | 4 |   |
|---+---+   |
| 5 | 6 |   |
+-----------+
```

I have tried to apply a negative margin/padding to the `.newsFeed` rule:

```
.newsFeed {
    // ... code
    // margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Obviously, this didn't work. Can anybody help me to solve this?

Merry Christmas!

Comment: firebug it up I think that your width is too narrow for .newsFeed

Comment: You can use the `:nth-child()` selector to change css properties for every Nth (in this case third) element.

Comment: post html as well as css

Comment: If the container is 728 pixels wide you have room for three elements that are max 242 pixels wide each. The elements are 253 pixels wide (width 233px + padding 5px + 5px + border 10px).

Comment: ah, I don't know how I could forgot about the `width+padding`...

Comment: total pixel for the maincontainer .newsFeed is 728px
...........................................................
less:.newsFeed li                       width: 233px;
      padding: 5px *2                =padding: 10px; right and left
                                 border-right: 10px
  ................................................................
  total pixel occupied by one div is          253px
  total pixel occupied by three divs are      759px
  so this reason it pushes the third div into the next row

Answer (score 3):

```
total pixel for the maincontainer .newsFeed is 728px
...........................................................
less:.newsFeed li                       width: 233px;
      padding: 5px *2                =padding: 10px; right and left
                                 border-right: 10px
  ................................................................
  total pixel occupied by one div is          253px
  total pixel occupied by three divs are      759px
  so this reason it pushes the third div into the next row
```

Answer (score 2):

Padding:5px also adds to the width (so 3*2*5 = 30px )

```
.newsFeed li {
width: 226px;
height: 244px;
padding: 5px;
border-right: 10px solid #dddddd;
margin: 0;
float: left;
}
.newsFeed li.last-item {
border-right: none;
}
```

Html

```
<ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li class="last-item"></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li class="last-item"></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: the `li.last-item` class will make things harder I suppose. since this is a jQuery computed news feed.

Comment: The css :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.  So you have to style the nth-child through jquery only adding above style definition

Comment: Actually, Microsoft is canceling the support for Windows XP in 2014, so Internet Expleror 6/7 are dead. Here, you can see the statistics, and you can know that only 0.6% of people use IE 6/7 . I don't have to target my website for these "expired versions" of browser. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: Not supported in IE 8 also.  IE8 supports first-child only and not even last-child

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions is that instead of using fixed sized `li` elements, you should use a percentage based size in conjunction with `box-sizing: border-box`

So a working code would be:

```
li {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
   width: 33%;
}
```

**Explanation:**

You are effectively giving a width of:

```
  233  - The 'inner' width
 +2*5  - Two times the padding
 +10   - The left border
 =253  - The effective width

 253*3 = 759 pixels
```

But you are only giving a pixel size of 728. Of course you could set the inner width to 759 pixels but a relative size with`box-sizing` would also allow a resizing of the list without having to change the individual values.

**Conclusion**
Use a relative width with `box-sizing` or set the list width to 759.

PS: Please do not use another class as it just pollutes the css classes.

**Edit**

[Oops, here also have a plunker showing a solution.](http://plnkr.co/edit/tE6n2tTtez0gK9CQjDi5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

An idea came to me:

I can use the [`nth-child()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) property with the `3n` attribute, so that I will only have 3, 6, 9, 12...

```
.newsFeed li:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right: none;
}
```

And this works.